# JavaScript update <a> href and then follow it and keep intended target

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href, intercept

I have a problem. I need to update href and then follow it. It may seem that it's quite easy task, because I just could return false, create new link element and then initialise click on it or maybe just change location.href...

So problem is: **How to know if user held [CTRL] button or right-clicked and chose one of Open in New Tab, Open in Incognito Tab or Open in New Window... or of course simply clicked with left-button...**

This href must be updated on click. Mouse hover may be an option but this will fail in mobile and tablets :)

P.S. if you give a negative evaluation it would be nice to know why :)

Comment: There is no way to know if the user used the context menu to open in a  new tab etc. best you can do is know when the context menu is opened. There generally is no need to "update and follow", all you do is `window.location.href = 'new_location'` in the click handler, and it redirects.

Comment: This smells a lot like trying to disable right-clicking on a webpage. All that happens is you'll annoy the hell out of your users!

Comment: I can't do any disabling because this is HUDGE portal, CQ5 and tons of other features... This link update is just to add params if map was open and if so - add latlng. But yea, I have a feeling that this is not possible.. Sounds kind of security issue if it would be possible

Comment: then add and remove latlng when opening and closing the map.

Comment: That map can be dragged anywhere, zoom changed and so on. Requirements says that this can not be updated on all user actions, just on final button click when user goes to the next details page. Those params are used to build breadcrumb in that next page so user would be able to get back to the same position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so here's a workaround for you:

### HTML

```
<a href="default_location">Click</a>
```

### JQuery

```
$('a').on('mouseenter focus', function() {
    // Re-write url
    $(this).attr('href', 'redirected_location');
});

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    // Prevent default behaviour (i.e. opening link)
    e.preventDefault();

    // Re-write url
    $(this).attr('href', 'redirected_location');

    // Re-direct to link
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

The idea here is that we rely on other user interaction, other than clicking, to re-write the HREF.

I have chosen `mouseenter` and `focus` to cover both mouse and keyboard events.

This means that the URL they will follow, even if they right-click and chose new window, will be correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Click event listener is not needed, because it opens link in the same tab.

Answer (score 0):

just send them to a redirect page with the refferal url.

```
<a href="https://www.MySite.com/redirect.php?refferal_href=https://www.google.com/">Link</a>
```

Then on the redirect page you do something like this.

```
header('Location: '.$_GET['refferal_href']);
```

And if you don't have php enabled use javascript to grab the redirection url.